# Laravel 5 - Defining middleware for multiple routes in controller file

Tags: php, laravel, controller, view, middleware

Stackers!
I'm currently learning laravel5 and I love it, but I'm struggling with one thing. Since Laravel 5 we have Middleware which we can use in controller's construct function, like this:

Controller file:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin', ['only' => 'create']);
}
```

Now what I want is to define HERE^ (not in routes file) middleware to be used in multiple views, like 'create', 'edit' and 'show'. defining

```
public function __construct()
{
            $this->middleware('admin', ['only' => 'create|edit|show']);
}
```

Unfortunately does not work. I'd rather not use routes. Any ideas, dear friends?

Comment: Hi, how do i use this for two roles, lets say Admin have access to all methods and Manager only have access to create, edit, show how can i do that ? how to write middleware for something like that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simply pass an array instead of a string with `|` delimiter:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin', ['only' => ['create', 'edit', 'show']]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, how do i use this for two roles, lets say Admin have access to all methods and Manager only have access to create, edit, show how can i do that ? how to write middleware for something like that.

Comment: @ChanukaAsanka Simply call `$this->middleware()` twice

Comment: ok .. you mean i should have two middlewar called Admin & Manager. but i don't know how to handle that in handle method.. 

 
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
                if (\Auth::user()->role == 'Manager') {
                        return true;
                }
                return $next($request);
}


can you provide example. 
basically i don't need to give permission to  delete for Manager

Comment: @ChanukaAsanka This isn't really related to this question anymore. Please ask a question yourself

Comment: Sure I'll post. Thanks for reply

Comment: You can do this ... $this->middleware('auth'); $this->middleware('customAuth'); .... and so on